# Spring can't parse valid LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, kotlin

I don't understand, what is wrong here? The date seems correct to me:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1971-04-29T00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 2
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:75)
at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:46)
...
```

If I just run this code, it works, so I assume it is some kind of Spring problem:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("1971-04-29T00:00:00")
```

The corresponding spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
class RecordController(
    val recordRepository: RecordRepository
) {

    @PostMapping("/records")
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    fun createRecord(
        @RequestBody
        record: RecordEntity
    ): RecordEntity {
        return recordRepository.save(record)
    }

    @GetMapping("/records")
    @ResponseBody
    fun getRecords(
        @RequestParam("from", required = false)
        from: LocalDateTime?,
        @RequestParam("to", required = false)
        to: LocalDateTime?,
        @RequestParam("client-type", required = false)
        clientType: ClientType?
    ): Iterable<RecordEntity> {
        var spec: Specification<RecordEntity> = where(null)!!
        if (from != null)
            spec = spec.andFrom(from)
        if (to != null)
            spec = spec.andTo(to)
        if (clientType != null)
            spec = spec.andClientTypeSpec(clientType)
        return recordRepository.findAll(spec)
    }

    fun Specification<RecordEntity>.andFrom(from: LocalDateTime): Specification<RecordEntity> {
        return and { root: Root<RecordEntity>, criteriaQuery: CriteriaQuery<*>?, criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder ->
            criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.get<LocalDateTime>("createdAt"), from)
        } ?: this
    }

    fun Specification<RecordEntity>.andTo(to: LocalDateTime): Specification<RecordEntity> {
        return and { root: Root<RecordEntity>, criteriaQuery: CriteriaQuery<*>?, criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder ->
            criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.get<LocalDateTime>("createdAt"), to)
        } ?: this
    }

    fun Specification<RecordEntity>.andClientTypeSpec(clientType: ClientType): Specification<RecordEntity> {
        return and { root: Root<RecordEntity>, criteriaQuery: CriteriaQuery<*>?, criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder ->
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get<ClientType>("clientType"), clientType)
        } ?: this
    }
}
```

The Entity Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECORDS")
class RecordEntity(
    @Id @Column(name = "BOOKING_ID")
    var bookingId: String,
    @Column(name = "CLIENT")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var clientType: ClientType,
    @Column(name = "CREATED_AT", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime
)
```

The Repository is rather boring:

```
@Repository
interface RecordRepository : CrudRepository<RecordEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<RecordEntity> {

}
```

The Rest call:

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8080/records?to=1971-04-29T00:00:00'
```

I'm not sure where the problem comes from, so I included all the code. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: I'd post this as an answer but I know zero about Kotlin.  From just a cursory scan of your code, you have defined two request fields ('from' and 'to') but the request provides only one.  What are you expecting to happen when `from` is missing? Does the trailing `?` tell Kotlin it's optional? If so where is the default value set?

Comment: @JimGarrison the ? Tells kotlin that it can be null and the default value by spring is null if marked as "required = false. That is the same in java just that kotlin types are usually not null and I need to tell that they can be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has a number of different conversion utilities for JDK types, like numbers and dates.

Specifically, Spring Boot, in order to setup the Spring MVC web infrastructure, uses [`DateTimeFormatterRegistrar`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeFormatterRegistrar.html) to register a bunch of different formatters for the date types in `java.time`.

As of this writing, for a `LocalDateTime`, it uses

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
```

For my system's `Locale`, this `DateTimeFormatter` produces formats like

```
12/19/20, 8:45 PM
```

From your error,

```
Text '1971-04-29T00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 2
```

I assume it does the same for parsing: index 2 would've been the position of the `/`.

There are a number of ways to fix this, like registering your own `DateTimerFormatterRegistrar`. The easiest solution, in my opinion, is to simply annotate your parameter with an appropriate `@DateTimeFormat`. For example,

```
@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to
```

This will force Spring MVC to use a separate `DateTimeFormatter` instance, capable of parsing your date-time string.